# Option to remove/convert milliseconds

Tags: php, laravel, iso, dateinterval

I have some troubles in dateinterval in php. Is there any option to remove digits after dot, or just convert them? 
I mean I have PT1H1.836S, and I would like to receive PT1H2S for example

```
$str = 'PT1H1.836S';
$arr = new DateInterval($str);
```

Comment: Can you show us some code that demonstrates your issue please

Comment: It is always best to place code in the question. Thats where others will look for information about your question

Comment: I already did it as u wish

Comment: That is not valid PHP. So what code are you really running?

Comment: I just coppied it so fast. It does not matter. I have only this error: **DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (PT1H1.836S)**

Comment: Exactly What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: You can do some PHP magic to strip out the `.836` part (the milliseconds) or take `1.836` and round it to the nearest integer, but the `DateInterval()` construct does not take milliseconds, and expects seconds to be of type integer.

Comment: I told you. I'm trying to achieve **PT1H2S** for example

Comment: Do you define the `$str` yourself, or do you get its value from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try somthing like that.

```
$str = "PT1H1.836S";
$xx1 = explode( '.', $str );
$xx2 = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $xx1[1] );
$final = $xx1[0].$xx2; 
print_r($final);
```

Comment: It works, but I thought there is another option ( already created ) to manipulate this